# Is it better to ask a new question than edit the existing one, when the existing one was pretty off track?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, asking-questions, editing

Regarding this question:

https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/18726/rudeness-back-biting-unprofessional-attitude-common-workplace-problem

The user initially asked 'Does my workplace suck, or is it just me?' (see [edit history](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/18726/revisions)), which listed several issues he has in his workplace. The question was put on hold.  He's since edited it to be more objective, and trying to narrow it to one issue.

With one of these too broad questions, where it's actually a pretty good, but not suitable/answerable question, I think keeping the original question and closing it and asking new questions, is better than editing the original, as it provides feedback for what makes a bad question.

Answer (score 2):

If the question is edited and improved to the point of being reopened then the question will do fine.  If it is just edited and reopened with out being improved, it will continue to get hammered.  If the OP asks a new question that is basically the same rant that this questions is, I would expect it would be less well received than the original.  The first one gets some benefit of the doubt that the OP did not know better.  The second one does not get that same benefit of the doubt.